# Zend Form: Add and Edit OK, but what about View?

Tags: php, zend-form

Following a Zend tutorial from a book I have created a Base Form and subclassed it twice - once for Edit, once for Create.  How should I go about creating a View only version?

All the View details are the same as the Edit version, but I don't want users to be able to edit any fields.

As a related question - there is one field in the Edit version that I don't want users to be able to edit.  What's the best way to achieve this?  Is javascript the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a 'view only' form, I have subclassed the Edit form, and included the following code:

```
$allElements = $this->getElements();
foreach ($allElements as $element) {
    $element->setAttrib('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you have all the fields set up in the base form then you can do this:

**Remove a field**

```
<?php
Application_Model_Form_BaseForm extends Zend_Form {

    public function init()
    {
        $this->addElement('text', 'baseElement', array('addDecoratorsInHere'));
    }
}

Application_Model_Form_EditForm extends Application_Model_Form_BaseForm {

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->removeElement('baseElement');
    }
}
```

**Disabling fields, view only**

Ive never done this myself but I guess you could create another form and set all fields to disabled.

```
<?php
Application_Model_Form_EditForm extends Application_Model_Form_BaseForm {

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->getElement('baseElement')->addDecorator(array('disabled' => 'disabled'));
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful.